# Silverlight datagrid Observable collection send a list of notifications

Tags: silverlight, performance, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

In my silverlight application I use a datagrid. The item source is an ObservableCollection< Customer > The Customer object implements INotifyPropertyChanged. The problem is that from second to second I update all customers elapsed time. If I have in the grid 5000+ records this is a problem for performance.

Do you know if it is possible to have in silverlight something like:

```
_grid.SuspendLayout();
//update model
_grid.ResumeLayout();
```

... or suspend bindings.

Since I update only elapsed time column I would like to update only that column ... not the whole grid. Does the datagrid support some event to receive a list of updates? In this case maybe I can think of implementing my custom ObservableCollection.

Comment: Hi. I created a small example to repoduce your problem. I created a small customer (only name and surname) and a second timer which is updated via a Dispatcher Timer each second. All properties throw the proeprties changed event. The DataGrid has AutoGenerateColumns an as ItemsSource an ObservableCollection with 6000 Customers. If I update the Seconds only the getter of the seconds is called, no other getter... So only the Seconds column is updated. My Grid gets a little slow after a while, but this could be, cause I create a Dispatcher for each object...  Could you provide some more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [OneTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx) binding mode instead of TwoWay?  If you use OneTime, you can decide to manually refresh the grid by saving changes on your context.  You can also control edits using `grid.BeginEdit()` and `grid.CommitEdit()`.